# in javascript which operation requires more work for the browser?

Tags: javascript

In javascript which operation requires more work for the browser?

```
var variable1;


// Operation 1
variable1 = 8;

// Operation 2
if (variable1 != 8) {

}
```

Comment: You mean which is costly assignment or comparison ??

Comment: [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) is a great tool for benchmarking code in your browser.  See a simple test case I set up at http://jsperf.com/assignment-versus-comparison

Comment: WHy is this getting voted down?

Comment: @jsPerf I tried your test case and the comparison seems much more efficent. Thx thats all i wanted to know

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd guess it was voted down because it's a question that you could have answered for yourself using jsPerf -- it doesn't require any special expertise or experience. (Of course, if you didn't know about jsPerf, you couldn't have.)

Comment: @Thomas Really? What browser(s) are you testing with?  I'm getting much faster results in favor of assignment. Chrome shows a factor of 13 speedup and Firefox shows a factor 6.  Note that the result numbers are reported in *operations per second*, so higher is better.

Comment: hm yeah your right apsillers. Not sure what i was looking at before. sorry. Oh assignment faster that is a suprise to me. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/assignment-versus-comparison) that I just made, assignment is much faster than comparison -- sometimes by an order of magnitude, depending on your browser.

I observed a weird bug in Firefox where the operations per minute result for assignment was  sometimes reported as "Infinity".  If that happens, simply run the test again.

Comment: Wow thanks guys for clarifying - this is great to know, especially for optimising time-critical functions on slow devices. I was always assuming it was the other way round - javascript, you nasty bugger ;)